# How do I bind member variable to JSON? - Android

Tags: android, json, retrofit, gson

I am using retrofit w/ gson annotations to bind my incoming JSON to a model and its member attributes to types like String, int, float, etc...

```
public class Location {

    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private int userId;
```

But how do I bind to a member variable that's of type JSON?  I want it to be unstructured which is why I can't just map it to a well-defined model.

```
    @SerializedName("metadata")
    @Expose
    private JsonObject metadata;
```

How do I get the above to work?

Comment: If you want to store array or list kinda data inside model `Location`, why not use a model class list

Comment: I have all the defined attributes tied w/ models or primitives.  Metadata is unstructured so the model might be different from response to response, hence why binding it to Json makes the most sense.

Comment: Your memeber variable should be a type of another ... having same name as the json object that you are receiving..if you dint get i will write am amswer..

Comment: You guys are completely missing the point of why I want this member attribute as JSON.

Comment: please explain it better..

Comment: Let's say you have `metadata` field.  User A has the key pair values: `{"animal" : "dog"}`.  User B might want to have their metadata field: `{"car" : "honda"}`.  This is why setting a defined model for the metadata variable doesn't work and why JSON makes architectural sense for this use-case.

Comment: so you want a variable like ... metadata which will directly hold json ..something like this `metadata = { "car" : "honda"}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I can set the member attribute to `JsonElement`

```
@SerializedName("metadata")
@Expose
private JsonElement metadata;
```

This resolves the issue of binding to JsonNull + JsonObject.

Comment: Thank you ! I don't think however `@SerializedName` is necessary if the field has the right name. Nor `@Expose` if Gson isn't configured with `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()`.